# If-else inside For Loop

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Unable to run this code, tried using if else statement inside for loop. Want to skip q6:q10 data. Please help. Using it in Google Appscript for google spreadsheet

```
  { var data1=[];;
  for(var i=0; i<dataLen; i++)


      for (q = 0;q<20;if (q=5, q+=4; else q++)      


      {
     data1[q]=data[i][q];
       }

      ss.appendRow(data1);
      flag="true";
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Using it in Google Appscript for google spreadsheet.

Comment: any errors? I don't know this language, but the `for (q...` seems to be missing a `)`

Answer (score 2):

The format and lack of context makes this question very confusing, but a loop like this solves your stated problem

```
var data1=[];
for(var i=0; i<dataLen; i++){
    for(q = 0; q < 20;q++){
        if(q == 7){
            q = 10;
        }
        data1[q] = data[i][q];

    }
}
```

If you would like to use 2 for loops, it would look like

```
var data1=[];
for(var i=0; i<dataLen; i++){
    for(q = 0; q < 7;q++){
        data1[q] = data[i][q];

    }
}
for(var i=0; i<dataLen; i++){
    for(q = 10; q < 20;q++){
        data1[q] = data[i][q];

    }
}
```

Comment: This is working perfectly fine. As you mentioned in the code column 6 and column 10 are not displayed. Just one issue those columns are not blank but with Value as "NOT_FOUND" . Ref here. http://screenshotlink.ru/1fe9cde924900e9d28d1f6046c1d96bc.png

Comment: Hey! That is correct, since you don't fill the column it has no value. I have edited the code such that it sets a value when the columns are 6 and 10. Hope this helps!

Comment: Quite close to what I wanted. As per your new code, value will be 0 instead of "NOT_FOUND". Is it possible to eliminate this column? I mean I would prefer next column data instead of blank space/"NOT_FOUND"/0, if there is any way to do the same.

Comment: It would help if you explain what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to shift the columns in the 6th and 10th position with every iteration? Or leave the column empty? Please fully explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I actually want to print column 1 to column 6 then column 10 to column 19 in same row. But I do not want column 7,8,9 to be filled with any value. SO the table would look like this.  Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col10 col11-col19. So I donot want a column7,8,9.

Comment: Now it is only displaying column 10, i think increment will be required too. But yes, I got the logics for the required code. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Just one more thing, if I have to achieve the same result using 2 for loops will it be possible. like for(q=0;q<7;q++) and then for(q=10;q<20;q++). If yes, how i can write this code. If you can answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really want, but I think you want something like this :

```
For(var i = 0; i<dataLen; i++){
   if(i%10 == 6||i%10 == 7||i%10 == 8||i%10 == 9||i%10 == 0){

   } else {
     data1[i]=data[q][i];
     ss.appendRow(data1);
     flag = "true";
  }
}
```

Comment: this code actually transfers data from one sheet to other. I want to transfer column 1 to column 5 then to skip column 6-10 then transfer again column 11 to 19.

Comment: In this code, change `if(...)` to `if(i>=6 && i<=10)`.

Comment: @RoshVerma try this

Comment: @RoshVerma now is better

Comment: Umm, just one thing it doesnt have to do anything with "i" since i is for rows and i want to skip columns i.e columns 6 to columns 10, so i think change will be in "q". sishaar rao has done it. Little improvisation needed there. :)

Comment: @RoshVerma yeh, i just changed the place of "i"  and "q", I usully ues i like a counter